# Populate WPF image from stream, doesn't scale correctly

Tags: c#, wpf

```
public static System.Drawing.Image GetImage() 
{
   // ... returns a System.Drawing.Image 
}
```

---

```
public partial class PreviewWindow : Window
{
    private void btnPreview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image page = GetImage();
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            page.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Position = 0;

            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
            bitmap.EndInit();
        }

        imgPreview.Source = bitmap;
        imgPreview.Stretch = Stretch.UniformToFill;
        imgPreview.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;
    }
}
```

I'm generating an image, returning it to the UI window as a `System.Drawing.Image` and displaying a preview of the image in a WPF `System.Windows.Controls.Image` component. This basically works.

The problem is it is not scaling. I want the image to keep its correct aspect ratio but shrink to fit the image component (the image will always be larger than the screen). There is no error message or exception, but the image is displayed at its full size but cropped in to the component space.

I've tried setting the scaling properties in the xaml and in code as above. I suspect it may be because it is loading from a stream rather than a resource. Is there some subtly I'm missing?

How do I make an image which is loaded in to a WPF Image component from a stream scale as described?

Comment: What is your exact expectation of a "correct scaling"? Does it not do what you expect from setting `Stretch.UniformToFill`?

Comment: Addressed in question edit, thanks :)

Comment: am voting to close my own question as I think the problem was system specific :/

Answer (score 1):

I'm not at all sure what you're doing wrong, but for me Stretch.Uniform and StretchDirection.Both do what I think it is you're asking for.

I took a screenshot of this webpage to test.  I put a big thick red border around the Image control.  I played with the dimensions of the Image control.  With it very tall or very wide I get results as below.  The image is resized but the aspect ratio remains the same and we get whitespace in the control as a result.  It's not cropped.  If that's not what you want say so.

[image: Control very tall]

[image: Control very wide]

The full code is below, this was done in .NET Core 3.1, but I doubt it makes any difference.  You get the same effect if you take the border out and put the Height and Width dimensions directly on the Image control, by the way.

C#

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void btnPreview_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        System.Drawing.Image page = GetImage();
        var bitmap = new BitmapImage();

        using (var ms = new MemoryStream())
        {
            page.Save(ms, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Bmp);
            ms.Position = 0;

            bitmap.BeginInit();
            bitmap.CacheOption = BitmapCacheOption.OnLoad;
            bitmap.StreamSource = ms;
            bitmap.EndInit();
        }

        imgPreview.Source = bitmap;
        imgPreview.Stretch = Stretch.Uniform;
        imgPreview.StretchDirection = StretchDirection.Both;
    }

    public static System.Drawing.Image GetImage()
    {
        return System.Drawing.Image.FromFile("sshot.jpg");
    }
}
```

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="ScalingTest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        xmlns:local="clr-namespace:ScalingTest"
        mc:Ignorable="d"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="800" Width="1100">
    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
        <Button x:Name="btnPreview" Content="Preview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="btnPreview_Click"/>
        <Border BorderThickness="3" BorderBrush="Red" Height="500" Width="1050" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top">
            <Image x:Name="imgPreview" HorizontalAlignment="Left" VerticalAlignment="Top"/>
        </Border>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You are correct, I made no changes and it is now working :/ The only thing which has changed is a restart of the machine! I think I might not be disposing of a component and it's somehow hanging on to an earlier version which I hadn't set the scaling on. Is this possible?? I will experiment.

Comment: By the way one possibility is you were setting the properties in the XAML AND the code and forgetting you'd done that.  I know it's possible because I was doing it for a bit and wondering why nothing was changing after editing the XAML.